# The more you're sinless vs the more sinless you are

Tags: idiomatic-language

> **The more you're sinless**
>
> The more I wanna bite
>
> **I'm lost inside of the night**
>
> So leave me here where I roam
>
> All on my own

On My Own - Hyde

Shouldn't it be "the more sinless you are"? The phrase used seems to be ungrammatial. Am I correct? Also, "lost inside of the night", is that grammatical too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a song, which is an example of poetry. The rules of grammar are often relaxed to the point of being almost nonexistent in poetry, especially sung poetry. This is not a new concept and has been explained many times on this site.

"The more you're sinless" doesn't truly make a lot of sense because "being sinless" is a binary thing—either you have sinned or you haven't. Someone who has *never* sinned would be called "sinless" and someone who as sinned *even once* wouldn't be. But things aren't so strict in songs and there isn't really a grammatical issue here.

Similarly, "lost inside of the night" is perhaps not as logically sound as it could be, but is perfectly fine from a grammar standpoint.

Comment: randomhead is right, though "lost inside **of**" is unusual in the UK. "Lost in(side) the night" might be more idiomatic here.

Comment: 'The more you're sinless' could, I suppose, possibly mean 'the more your lack of sin becomes clear to me'. I wonder if the singer is addressing Jesus, because in the milieu in which 'sin' is a thing, only he was/is without sin? or it could mean something else. Or nothing. It's a song, right?

Comment: Or, 'the more I idealise you'?